# how to select distinct fields grouped by one field and concat one field with delimiter in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, distinct, group-concat

I have an table that includes these field :

table phonebook

```
 id   
 user_id
 number
 name
 added
 card_id
 speeddial
 updated_at
 sms_group_name
```

some records have same sms_group_name and number,but there is some duplicate number for same sms_group_name. First I want to take distinct number for each sms_group_name and group_concat with , delimiter.

query result must be like this :

user_id, number,number,number,number,sms_group_name

select where condition is user_id

I tried all of them :

```
# @a = Phonebook.select(["DISTINCT number","sms_group_name"]).where(user_id: session[:user_id]).order(:sms_group_name).distinct
# @a = Phonebook.where(user_id: session[:user_id])
# Product.where.not(restaurant_id: nil).select("DISTINCT ON(name) name, restaurant_id, price, updated_at").order("name, updated_at")
# @a = Phonebook.where(user_id: session[:user_id]).select("DISTINCT ON(number) number, added, user_id, speeddial, updated_at,sms_group_name").order("sms_group_name")
# Phonebook.select("DISTINCT(number), *").where("user_id = ?", session[:user_id]).order("sms_group_name ASC").group_by(&:sms_group_name)
# Location.where("calendar_account_id = ?", current_user.calendar_accounts.first).group(:alias).order("alias ASC").group_by(&:category)
# @a = Phonebook.where("user_id = ?", session[:user_id]).order("sms_group_name ASC").group(:sms_group_name)
# @a = Phonebook.select("DISTINCT(number), sms_group_name").where("user_id = ?", session[:user_id]).order("sms_group_name ASC").group_by(&:sms_group_name)
# @a = Phonebook.select(:number)distinct.where("user_id = ?", session[:user_id]).order("sms_group_name ASC").group_by(&:sms_group_name)
# @a = Phonebook.select("DISTINCT(number), sms_group_name").group("sms_group_name")
```

most of them give error or does not work.

how can achive this ?

I tried select all values into object array ,after that I tried to eliminate them, but there is no suitable solution for now.

what can be solutions for both: 
1- solution by using query and may be added one block 
2- solution by using hash or array

best regards,

Comment: Try this query `Phonebook.select("DISTINCT ON (number,sms_group_name) number,sms_group_name").where(user_id: session[:user_id]).order(:sms_group_name).group_by{ |p| p.sms_group_name }` let me know if it is working or not

Comment: might be worth mentioning what database you are using

Comment: that query gave "Mysql2::Error" . also I use mysql server.

Comment: I want to explain detailed : I want to take result as a <ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Phonebook user_id: 5, number: "xxxxx,xxxxxx,xxxxxx", sms_group_name: "tem1">, #<Phonebook user_id: 5, number: "xxxxx,xxxxxx,xxxxxx", sms_group_name: "tem2">